# Review star issue

Tags: magento2, product, template, review

```
<div class="rating-summary"></div>
```

The rating-summary div is not showing on product page and category page

Only is showing the count of reviews.

[image]

Magento 2.x

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * @description:
 *
 */
?>
<?php
    $_items = $block->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();
    $format = $block->getDateFormat() ?: \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT;
?>
<?php if (count($_items)):?>
<div class="block review-list" id="customer-reviews">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Customer Reviews') ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="toolbar review-toolbar">
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('toolbar') ?>
        </div>
        <ol class="items review-items">
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_review):?>
            <li class="item review-item" itemscope itemprop="review" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
                <div class="review-title" itemprop="name"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_review->getTitle()) ?></div>
                <?php if (count($_review->getRatingVotes())): ?>
                    <div class="review-ratings">
                    <?php foreach ($_review->getRatingVotes() as $_vote): ?>
                    <div class="rating-summary item" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
                        <span class="label rating-label"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_vote->getRatingCode()) ?></span></span>
                        <div class="rating-result" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_vote->getPercent() ?>%">
                            <meta itemprop="worstRating" content = "1"/>
                            <meta itemprop="bestRating" content = "100"/>
                            <span style="width:<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_vote->getPercent() ?>%">
                                <span itemprop="ratingValue"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_vote->getPercent() ?>%</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="review-content" itemprop="description">
                    <?php echo nl2br($block->escapeHtml($_review->getDetail())) ?>
                </div>
                <div class="review-details">
                    <p class="review-author">
                        <span class="review-details-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Review by')?></span>
                        <strong class="review-details-value" itemprop="author"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_review->getNickname()) ?></strong>
                    </p>
                    <p class="review-date">
                        <span class="review-details-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Posted on') ?></span>
                        <time class="review-details-value" itemprop="datePublished" datetime="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt(), $format) ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt(), $format) ?></time>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
        <div class="toolbar review-toolbar">
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('toolbar') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Maybe it is displayed none using CSS.Inspect the HTML content and check

Comment: it will under review tab, also in your website customer must need login or create the account to view the reviews

Comment: @AmitBera I have checked. did not use CSS. Actually, review-summary div not displayed there.

Comment: @kunj Also login my account. But, Review not display under review tab, product view page and on product under category.

Comment: Only is showing count every page

Comment: Please check Magento logs because Magento review ajax returning blank in your website..

Comment: @kunj I have checked. <?php $rating = $block->getRatingSummary(); ?> got the result in $rating  = 0;  But, I have give the review 1.

Comment: 1 review actual result $rating = ?. Please tell me.

Comment: check `your theme path/Magento_Review/templates/product/view/list.phtml` file code your custome modules files.

Comment: @Kunj  I have checked when I approved pending review. The value inserted null in the rating_summary column in the database. It is Magento default functionality.

Comment: Please share the code of that `list.phtml`

Comment: How to send the code?  character not allowed @kunj

Comment: add that code in question.

Comment: Please check I have added code @kunj

Comment: Any option review enable or disable  in magento 2.x @kunj

Comment: yes, from admin Marketing > User Content > Reviews. You can approve reviews from there.

Comment: Any option in Magento review summary disable @kunj

Comment: Not getting you

Comment: Approve option got me, But I asked where is review star disable enable option? @kunj

Comment: I think we can do by only coding

Comment: Do you want to hide/disable this "4 Reviews" ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81310/discussion-on-question-by-masud-shaikh-review-star-issue).

Answer (score 0):

No need to change code, I think its backend configuration issue

Just move to Dashboard >> Attributes >> Rating set rating status of product,Quality etc. from `inactive` to `active`.